# Dynamics CRM 2011 external web site vs ISV in CRM 4

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4

I have to update code made for CRM 4. It consists of custom aspx pages which are in ISV folder.

I created a custom web site and hosted it on the same server where CRM is. It is configured with anonymous authentication and I pass a user id as query string parameter to set it as CallerId on the proxy. Code builds a hierarchy tree of an entity. Most of users have Business Unit level of privileges, but some records from other BU are shared with a team they are member of.

The problem is that the code runs far much slower than as ISV deployed. What could be the reason for this? When I run the code with crmadmin credentials, it goes faster, even if I run RetrievePrincipalAccessResponse for each product, it runs faster.

Appriciate any suggestion

Comment: also if not officially supported, ISV folder still works with CRM 2011 (it has been completely removed starting from CRM 2013)

Comment: I know, we are on CRM 2011 and planning upgrade to 2013, that is why I have to deal with this now.